# Why there is not a random access array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, language-design

The PHP array is in fact an *ordered map that associates values to keys*. The access to random numerical indices is considerably slower than it is in languages like Java. Even Javascript array access is significantly faster than PHP. I experienced the slowness of PHP when I programmed Sudoku solutions on the server and switched finally to Python, that was also faster than PHP.

What is the reason that PHP does not provide a proper random access array (for numerical indices)?

To clarify: I am not speaking about randomnes of the entries. I mean direct access via computed indices, e.g. having an array `a` of 81 values (Sudoku board) and accessing any value `a[i]` directly without searching a map.

Comment: Have you both try shuffle() and array_rand() ? Maybe one is faster than the other

Comment: why a language has a feature or does something that others don't? why english doesn't use useful letters that help you pronounce like spanish does?

Comment: I find it funny how people usually blame the language and yet they don't post the algorithm they used. I saw many Java programs compared to C++ programs that did the same job, yet C++ outperformed Java by hundreds of times. Natural conclusion was - oh man, Java sucks. When in reality, it was the algorithm that was bad. Without seeing the algorithm you used for random access, it's difficult to say why it was slow. Not only that, there are number of optimizations available to PHP, from the usual config ones to actually patching ZE with newer code that's not yet released.

Comment: I can't tell if this is an actual question or a troll...

Comment: You can use a binary `$string[$i]` for direct indicies. Would be simple enough and applicable to your Sudoku example.

Comment: I don't know what you consider slow. On my test PC it takes 0.6 seconds to create an array with 1 million entries and less than a millisecond to access any of the entries. JS will be faster due to the way it's executed (JIT-ing, no VM, direct assembly code) and it will probably beat many other languages out there, not just PHP, however - I don't think that less than a millisecond is slow. No human being can notice the difference between 1 and 2 millisecond, let alone less than that.

Comment: @N.B.: thanks for your investigation. I have an array with indices [0, 1000). I access each index 10'000 times. This takes approx. in PHP 5 secs, in Python 2.1 secs, and in JS 0.6 sec.

Comment: Check out the link in my answer. It has a list of performance comparisons between array and SplFixedArray with one on random access.

Comment: @Jiri - do you access the php arrays from within a loop? There's also performance difference between for loop and foreach loop. Paul - SplFixedArray helps only creating the array, not accessing it.

Comment: @Furicane yes, looking at it closely I guess it does less than i thought.  But the choice of random function was a big contributor.  We are yet to find out what was used.

Comment: @Furicane: in my perf. test I access a[i] in a for-loop: `for ($i = 0; $i < ...; ++$i) $x = $a[$i]`. This is the correct measure. I want to measure random direct access to a[i], not a contiguous loop.

Comment: @Jiri - have you tried to use xdebug to see what exactly takes up the CPU time? Since php array is a hash map internally, using direct access of $a[$i] **should** not take this long since there's not that much computing involved, and even ZE (as crappy as it is) shouldn't take 5 seconds to complete. I know that PHP data types take up more memory than C native types so memory would be exhausted faster. xdebug might shed some light on what actually goes on. I'll try to replicate what you did and I'll post results as soon as I do since I'm interested as well if it's true that PHP is **that** slow

Comment: @Jiri - 0.5 seconds to create a 1 million entry array, 0.005 seconds to access 10000 randomly chosen keys. When ran with HPHPi it takes 0.003 seconds to access 10K random keys in the array. I wouldn't call that slow.

Comment: @N.B.: exactly! You access 10^4 indices in 5*10^-3 secs, so you have 5*10^-7 sec/access. I access 10^7 indices in 5 secs, equals 5*10^-7 sec/access, the same as you!. You call it fast and I call it slow when I compare with 10-times faster access in JS. When you generate valid Sudoku boards, you need to construct a lot of all possible boards, which are 5*10^9. So, it makes a difference for the user if he gets a new board say in 20 secs or in 2 secs. In my case PHP was so slow that the HTTP connection timed out. (Python was sufficiently fast to do it.)

Comment: @Jiri you were talking about array **access** and by all means - it is quick. 3 milliseconds to access 10 thousand keys is **not** slow, I think you confused something in my notation there. Creating a huge array (10 million entry one) is slow (it took 5 seconds). On the other hand, yes, JS beats some languages like Java, depending on the  JS engine executing the code. V8 will translate everything to assembly, use JIT and various other techniques to boost performance so it'll fly and be effective (its garbage collection is awesome as well).

Comment: @N.B. yes, I see, so your access is at least 10 times faster than mine, caused likely by your environment. All these numbers are relative. The core point was in my question: why (in addition to the associative hash/map) there is no array with direct access to indices as in Java, C, and likely also JS. This array would be surely faster than any associative hash/map. But it seems that it is just a coincidence without deep reasons that PHP omits arrays. So a C++/Java programmer, like me, has to look for alternatives when he programs Web applications with many vector/matrix operations.

Comment: @Jiri - php arrays are implemented as hashmaps so you can have near-infinite amount of array dimensions. Typing something like `a[i][j][k][l] = 1` in C would exhaust memory pretty fast even for small amount of index values while in PHP you can go deep as you want to since internally it's just a 1-d array. You mention direct access, I'm assuming you refer to the internal data-structure that PHP creates - well, why would you need it? I also doubt that my environment can cause that my script executes 5000 times faster (5sec vs 5 millisecs). Post your entire algorithm and let's check it out.

Comment: @N.B.: I was right, we are equally fast. You have `0.005 seconds to access 10K randomly chosen keys`. I have `5 seconds to access 10'000K randomly chosen keys`. An array is of course not optimal for sparse matrices. Even if I did not get an answer to my question, it was interesting to have this discussion. I thank you very much!

Comment: @Jiri SplFixedArray is the kind of array you have been talking about.  Direct access, no hash.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a difference in language design.  It's difficult to compare "language X" is faster than "language Y" in terms of something like a Sudoku solver.  The performance gain really boils down to implementation.

However, PHP arrays are stored internally as [ordered hashes](https://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_hash.h).

If you're looking for a performance gain with arrays and sets, try looking at some of [these](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php).  They might fit your dataset better.  It's about choosing the right tool - PHP arrays seem to be this "catch-all" structure that people love to shove all their data in, and it's a pattern with which I disagree.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe one of the SPL array types would have suited you better?

[PHP SPL manpage](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php)

**Edit:** Looking more closely at it, the SplFixedArray would be a good choice for a sudoku implementation where you will know the size of the array.  It says itself that it would be faster.  However as others have said - without looking at the algorithm how can we be sure that the arrays were the problem?

[Perfomance comparison](http://blog.shay.co/phps-native-array-vs-splfixedarray-performance/) of array vs SplFixedArray

SPL - stands for Standard PHP Library, its nothing too scary

Comment: thanks for the links, I will look at it. The mentioned blog is also interesting and supports me in considering PHP "arrays" slow. In the words of S.B.Moshe: "PHP arrays... there still is a drawback. It damages performance."

Answer (score 1):

I guess, php was designed as a template engine for html pages. It has to be very simple, and very easy to use, with all necessary constructs / functions needed for a typical web application, iterating thorugh database fields, etc...

The speed was never an issue for php applications, as filesystems, database access and web services are uasually slower than php cpu processing alone.

Answer (score 1):

An array with intral indices `0 .. length - 1` is, in theory, **just a special case of associative arrays**, namely an associative array with the keys `0 .. length - 1`.

Of course the lookup algorithm is more involved, and generally you can't get O(1) in the worst case. But you do get armortized O(1) provided the hash function and hashtable implementation is any good (and in widely-used language implementations where it's a fundamental data type, it probably is). Also, it is entirely possible to use an (non-associative) array behind the scence for hash tables when most or all keys are integers, which rules out 90% of the overhead while operating with these indices. Lua 5 does it, I don't know if current PHP versions do it too.

If all that isn't enough and lookups are still too slow for your purpose, then the other answer apply: Improve your algorithm. (Really. Don't move to other options lightheartedly.) You may also be able to find a library that provides one (although it's questionable whether it's really faster, especially if it's written in PHP) or you may move the computationally intense parts into another language (and if you need to do *that*, you may as well go all the way and write it in C). But generally, a hashtable should be fast enough.

Comment: This all might be correct. My question should have been much clearer, but perhaps I did not post it in a clear way. In languages like Java, C, etc, the array is a fundamental data structures and nobody would like to miss it because of its excellent properties. Why there is this simple structure missed in PHP and simulated by a complicated hash table?

Comment: @Jiri: Why should there be a seperate type for it? Is there any difference for the user? We get to use bracket notation (`$arr[0] = ...;`, `$x = $arr[0];`) for getting and setting and you even get syntactic sugar for appending at the end (`$arr[] = ...;`). The implementation may be more complex, but the same is true for most high-level abstractions. So you say we should go back to C, where the standard library is small and simple but very low-level and hence inconvenient?

Comment: it would be useful to have both: a proper array with a fast direct index access and an associative map, as it is e.g. in Java. This would not make PHP more low-level as it is already. And why: because a direct access array is considerably faster than a hashmap and this would be noticed even by the user. This applies of course only to applications that use a lot of vector/matrix operations.

Comment: @Jiri: If there any reason apart from performance benefits - which only apply to rather specialized purposes, as you say yourself? Because that doesn't seem like a particular strong motivation for a language like PHP, which started as and for many people still is a lightweight scripting language for embedding a bit of dynamicness into HTML pages.

Comment: yes, I agree - this would be an answer. By my question I hoped to get some deeper insights about these design decisions for PHP. Thanks!

Comment: One reason would be intent. When you have a List, you have N values. When you have a Map, you have N keys and values. Sure, they can be used the same way, but using the right data structure can convey the intent of the code. Much the same as a Set implies that each value is distinct.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how did you try to randomize it. If you used big for loop you shouldn't be suprised it was slow. Use `rand()` for this purpose

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about randomizing array values, but rather accessing *any* value at any time.

Comment: docs say that mt_rand() is faster and works better, in any case

Comment: The question is not about random numbers.